# On the statement of the Dominated Convergence Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, convergence-divergence

The Dominated Convergence Theorem states the following:

For $f_n:X\to\mathbb{C}$ measurable functions with $f_n\to f$ almost everywhere, and $|f_n|\leq G$ for some measurable absolutely integrable function $G: X\to [0,\infty]$, then:

$$\lim\int_{X} f_n \;d\mu=\int_{X} f\;d\mu$$

I'm very confused on why we are considering $f_n$ bounded by a function $G: X\to [0,\infty]$ (this is not a typo, including $\infty$). Why is $G$ allowed to take on a value of $\infty$? I know it has to be absolutely integrable, so it can't be the constant function $\infty$, but why can we consider this?

Comment: I think this is only a detail. Since $G$ is integrable, it can only be infinite on a set of measure $0$ anyway.

Comment: We "can consider this" because the proof of the theorem shows it's correct. You don't give any reason why we _shouldn't_ allow $G(x)=\infty$...

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich What was tripping me up is that I failed to recognize at first that $G$ must be absolutely integrable. In other words, if we don't allow for this, we can allow $G$ to be the constant function $\infty$. Now that we require $G$ to be absolutely integrable, it means that it's finite almost everywhere. I missed this at first.

Comment: I feel like in a lot of these theorems that I'm learning in my measure theory course, allowing $G$ to be a function taking values of $\infty$ is there for the sake of being more general, and provides no actual extra information. It's happened several times where allowing some function to take a value of $\infty$ provides nothing, and this trips me up sometimes.

Comment: Allowing $G$ to take the value $\infty$ on some measure-zero set can be useful. It means we can apply the theorem directly in cases where the $f_n$ fail to be dominated on that measure-zero set. Otherwise, we 'd have to start such an application of the theorem by observing that the $f_n$ can be adjusted to be bounded, without changing any of the integrals. It's easier to make that observation once, in the dominated convergence theorem than to make it in lots of applications

Comment: @AndreasBlass not that important: can be adjusted to be _finite_, not bounded...